# tsql where clause find a value from subquery's top 1 value

Tags: t-sql

We have a slow query something like this:

```
select id
from task t 
inner join TaskLog tl 
on t.id = tl.id
where tl.PostImage = 
( 
    select top 1 tll.PostImage 
    from TaskLog tll 
    where tll.id = t.id     
)
group by t1.PostImage, t.id
```

It looked like the tl.PostImage = (subquery) caused the slowness. How do I rewrite this to make it run faster?

EDIT:

I have simplified the question in an incorrect way. Because of this the solution was not helped me. Here is the actual query I had:

```
SELECT  distinct(p.Task_id), 1 as TotalReferrals
FROM    Task p inner join Task_Log PL on PL.Task_ID = P.Task_ID  
where  (MONTH(P.CreateDate) = @Month
AND     YEAR(P.CreateDate) = @Year)

and  (((p.Worker like 'k3%'
and     p.CreateDate  < '12/6/2010')

or     (p.Worker  in ('k22', 'k27', 'k29')
and     p.CreateDate >= '12/6/2010' and p.ModifiedDate < '12/1/2013')

or     (p.Worker in ('K4A', 'K46', 'K48')
and     p.CreateDate >= '12/1/2013'))

or     (pl.post_image = (select top 1 pll.post_image
                         from    Task_log pll
                         where   pll.Task_id = p.Task_id
                         and     pll.pre_image = 'Unknown'
                         and     pll.changed_column_nm = 'Worker'
                         and    (Month(pll.CreateDate) = @Month
                         and     Year(pll.CreateDate) = @Year)
                         and   ((pll.post_image like 'k3%'
                         and     pll.CreateDate < '12/6/2010')
                          or    (pll.post_image in ('k22', 'k27', 'k29')
                         and     pll.CreateDate >= '12/6/2010' and pll.CreateDate < '12/1/2013')
                         or     (pll.post_image in ('K4A', 'K46', 'K48')
                         and     pll.CreateDate >= '12/1/2013'))
                         group by pll.post_image, pll.log_id
                        )
       ))
group by pl.post_image, p.Task_id, pl.CreateDate
```

Comment: What are the relative sizes of the tables? Are there any indexes in use?

Comment: Yes index was used. size of the tables are not small. But there are conditions filtered them out. I just didn't put those conditions in here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Am I just totally out of it, or is that `where` not necessary? I might be totally out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Min(T.id)
FROM Task T
INNER JOIN TaskLog TL 
ON T.id = TL.id
GROUP BY TL.PostImage
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: edits happen... that's part of being on Stack Overflow - people improve things to make them easier to read, while maintaining the original intent and knowledge. and upper-casing can make the SQL-specific words clearer to see (and thus make it obvious which bits are the query). It's pretty common across industry to use uppercase for the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to erase the subselect:

```
SELECT  Distinct(P.Task_id), 1 as TotalReferrals
FROM    Task P
INNER JOIN
        Task_Log PL
ON      PL.Task_ID = P.Task_ID  
WHERE  (MONTH(P.CreateDate) = @Month
AND     YEAR(P.CreateDate) = @Year)

AND  (((P.Worker like 'k3%'
AND     P.CreateDate  < '12/6/2010')

OR     (P.Worker  in ('k22', 'k27', 'k29')
AND     P.CreateDate >= '12/6/2010' and P.ModifiedDate < '12/1/2013')

OR     (P.Worker in ('K4A', 'K46', 'K48')
AND     P.CreateDate >= '12/1/2013'))

OR     (PL.pre_image = 'Unknown'
AND     PL.changed_column_nm = 'Worker'
AND     Month(PL.CreateDate) = @Month
AND     Year(PL.CreateDate) = @Year
AND    (PL.post_image like 'k3%'
AND     PL.CreateDate < '12/6/2010')
OR     (PL.post_image in ('k22', 'k27', 'k29')
AND     PL.CreateDate >= '12/6/2010' 
AND     PL.CreateDate < '12/1/2013')
OR     (PL.post_image in ('K4A', 'K46', 'K48')
AND     PL.CreateDate >= '12/1/2013'))
GROUP BY PL.post_image, P.Task_id, PL.CreateDate
```

Comment: Hi Mirco, your solution's result didn't match my original query's result.